# Value of coordinates() for a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object?

Tags: r, spatial, rgdal, r-sp

I am trying to get a pseudo barycenter for polygons in a spatial polygon dataframe. Today I stumbled upon the `coordinates` function that actually returns something for a *SpatialPolygonsDataFrame*.

Unfortunately I found nothing in the help of `coordinates` about the value for *SpatialPolygonsDataFrame*. Could somebody tell me what these coordinates are?

Comment: it's a centroid, just the geometric middle, not guaranteed to intersect thr polygon

Comment: @mdsumner would you have any reference on how it is computed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the polygon centroid. The source code is found [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/sp/src/sp_xports.c?view=markup&root=rspatial), look for function `FindCG`. The equations computed are equivalent to those found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon), but in addition deal with the special case of polygons with (near) zero area, and normalize polygon coordinates by the first point (to increase numerical precision and/or avoid overflow).

Comment: you probably mean findCG? Also how did you figure out that this specific piece of code is defining the labpt slot?

Comment: Yes. The constructor functions at some stage call there C counterpart, e.g. the`Polygon` R function calls `.Call(Polygon_c, coords, n, ihole)` which calls the underlying C function `Polygon_c`; these call then other C functions in turn. I am maintainer of sp, and author of large parts of it, although not these parts.

Comment: Great, can you correct your answer adding that to it, specially the correction? Also I just posted this question I would greatly appreciate look at : http://stackoverflow.com/q/29629049/1174052

Answer (score 0):

Reading the definition of coordinates for *SpatialPolygonsDataFrame* I can see that it is actually the same than `getSpPPolygonsLabptSlots` as it retrieves the `labpt` slot, that is to say a convenient point to put a label for the polygon.

```
> selectMethod("coordinates",signature="SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
Method Definition:

function (obj, ...) 
{
    .local <- function (obj) 
    {
        ret = t(sapply(slot(obj, "polygons"), function(i) slot(i, 
            "labpt")))
        dimnames(ret) = list(sapply(slot(obj, "polygons"), function(i) slot(i, 
            "ID")), NULL)
        ret
    }
    .local(obj, ...)
}
```