# Calculus for the labpt slot of a SpatialPolygon object

Tags: r, rgdal

The labpt slot of the SpatialPolygon object in the `sp` package is vaguely defined in the documentation as a point where a label is displayed for the polygon. I would like to know the calculation behind it and what are it's properties. Typically are we sure that it will be in the polygon or like a centroid it can be out of the polygon?

I found a function in the `rgeos` package computing a similarly named object but cannot figure out if it actually is the function used by sp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the centroid of the polygon with minor adaptations as well described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29603381/1174052) to a question about `coordinates()` which actually extract `labpt` from `SpatialPolygon` objects.