# How to modify a polygon to be a hole (SpatialPolygons) changing its slots

Tags: r, spatial, r-sp

## Edit:

As suggested by Edzer Pebesma in the comments, the recommended method to add a hole to a polygon is not to modify the slot but to rebuild  the polygon, as illustrated [in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29647822/1174052).

## Original question

Following the help of `SpatialPolygons-class` I tried to modify a polygon to be a hole of an other polygon but while the "hole polygon" is displayed as a border of the other polygon, its inside is colored as the rest.

What am I doing wrong?

Using `defPunched` and `defHole` defined [here](http://spatcontrol.net/CorentinMBarbu/misc/holeIssue.rda):

```
library("sp")
load(url("http://spatcontrol.net/CorentinMBarbu/misc/holeIssue.rda"))
defHole@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@hole<-TRUE
OnePolDFToPolygon <- function(x){
     main <- x@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]
     return(main)
 }
punch <- Polygons(list(OnePolDFToPolygon(defPunched),OnePolDFToPolygon(defHole)),defPunched@polygons[[1]]@ID)
mine <- SpatialPolygons(list(punch),proj4string=defPunched@proj4string)
mine <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(mine,data=as(defPunched,"data.frame"))
plot(mine,col="blue",border="green")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Holes are supposed to have the opposite ring direction, e.g. by

```
mine@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[2]]@coords = mine@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[2]]@coords[5:1,]
plot(mine, col = 'blue')
```

you get the plot below. Where did this data come from?

[image]

Comment: Why would you need to know where these data come from?

Comment: I assume you mean a bug in `Polygon`, or its documentation. But I see no `Polygon` call in your example. First, your example starts with R data for which we don't know where it comes from, then you directly assign values to slots, which is not recommended (meaning: at your own risk).

Comment: I would be glad not to manipulate directly slots but what is the recommended procedure to convert a polygon into a hole?

Comment: Also the two polygons are just subsets of a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, imported with "rgdal" from a kml generated in Google Earth.

Comment: recommended is using the sp constructor functions `Polygon`, `Polygons`, `SpatialPolygons` etc, as the documentation sais. Please publish your kml and the procedure you used to read it in R. Is your hole a hole on google earth?

Comment: Maybe we can continue the discussion in the R public chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public