# R extract vector of points from spatialpolygonsdataframe

Tags: r, polygon, spatial

I have a `spatialpolygonsdataframe` of the state of Iowa called `Iowa.sp`, which contains 99 polygons. I'm trying to extract all of the `labpt` values from each polygon as these are the centroids of each county in Iowa and I need to work with those values as references.

I can get an individual value for `labpt` from one polygon within the data frame using this:

```
Iowa.sp@polygons[[1]]@labpt
```

But have not been able to figure out how to extract the entire list of `labpt` values and am struggling with how to work within the `spatialpolygonsdataframe`. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to say exactly without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), but if that's the way you extract the `labpt` slot from *one* polygon, you should be able to use an `apply`- or `map`-family function to extract that slot from *each* polygon

Answer (score 0):

```
temp<-data.frame(xcoord=NULL,ycoord=NULL)
for( i in 1: length(türkiye@polygons[[1]]@Polygons)){ temp<-rbind(temp,data.frame(
 xcoord=türkiye@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[i]]@labpt[1],ycoord=türkiye@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[i]]@labpt[2]))}
temp
```

adapt your data according to this example.may be there are easier ways.
look at this question too 
[Value of coordinates() for a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565769/value-of-coordinates-for-a-spatialpolygonsdataframe-object/29603381#29603381)